# Images in content from another url doesnt appear on frontend

Tags: magento2, image

Images with another url than our own: https://takoda.shop

Doesn't appear on frontend but broken.

While images from our own url does appear.

Can't find a solution for this, anybody knows?
See here:

https://takoda.shop/en/catalog/product/view/id/281/s/crochet-bag-turquoise/category/37/

Answer (score 0):

if you check at your console log, you will see an error message from the CSP (Content Security Policy).
Basically it tells you that it's dangerous to use an external file. So if you still want to use it, you need to make an exception of it.

In order to do that I suggest you to create a custom module to handle the csp

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_CSP" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

Then you gonna need some other files

> src/app/code/Vendor/ContentSecurityPolicy/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront>
                    <report_only>0</report_only>
                </storefront>
                <admin>
                    <report_only>0</report_only>
                </admin>
            </mode>
            <policies>
                <storefront>
                    <frame-ancestors>
                        <inline>0</inline>
                    </frame-ancestors>
                </storefront>
            </policies>
        </csp>
    </default>
</config>
```

This is the file where all the magic appears. There is a custom file I had as a structural exemple, you just have to adapt to your own requirements in your own csp errors.

> src/app/code/Vendor/ContentSecurityPolicy/etc/csp_whitelist.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
                <value id="cookiebotScript" type="host">*.cookiebot.com</value>
                <value id="bing" type="host">*.bing.com</value>
                <value id="pinimg" type="host">*.pinimg.com</value>
                <value id="dwin1" type="host">*.dwin1.com</value>
                <value id="criteo" type="host">*.criteo.com</value>
                <value id="clarityOne" type="host">https://www.clarity.ms/tag/uet/25149270</value>
                <value id="clarityTwo" type="host">https://www.clarity.ms/eus-f/s/0.6.37/clarity.js</value>
                <value id="adservicegoogle" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                <value id="googleadservicescript" type="host">https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>

            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="img-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="klarna-base" type="host">*.klarna.com</value>
                <value id="googleadservices" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="vimeocdn" type="host">*.vimeocdn.com</value>
                <value id="youtube-img" type="host">*.ytimg.com</value>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self' data:</value>
                <value id="lightemporium" type="host">*.lightemporium.com</value>
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
                <value id="bing" type="host">*.bing.com</value>
                <value id="pinterest" type="host">*.pinterest.com</value>
                <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
                <value id="googleFr" type="host">*.google.fr</value>
                <value id="clarityOneGif" type="host">https://c.clarity.ms/c.gif</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="connect-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="bing" type="host">*.bing.com</value>
                <value id="pinterest" type="host">*.pinterest.com</value>
                <value id="googleadservices" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                <value id="google-analyticsConnect" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="google-clarityCollect" type="host">https://m.clarity.ms/collect</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="font-src">
            <values>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
                <value id="bootstrapcdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>

        <policy id="frame-src">
            <values>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="cookiebot" type="host">*.cookiebot.com/</value>
                <value id="criteo" type="host">*.criteo.com/</value>
            </values>
        </policy>

        <policy id="form-action">
            <values>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

EDIT : The simplies way would be to just setup the csp to show only the error messages without affecting your website. But i would still deeply recommend to keep using them properly and making the exception this way. Otherwise the report only tag config is enough to make your image appearing again by updating the config.

Comment: thank you, will dive into it later

Comment: I am very grateful, it is still a little bit to technical for me, the funny part is, I switch to another theme, since then the images doesn't seem to appear, before they were.

Comment: Doest it mean you manage to got your image ? Otherwise, all the details is explained into the magento doc : https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/content-security-policies/

Comment: not yet because i looks pretty difficult to do

Comment: Does someone has a easier option to solve this? Now I have everywhere broken images, it did work before.

Comment: Succeeded, by adding the url from an external source to:      <policy id="img-src">